# Objects in function not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, object

basically I want to practice using function and object to achieve the goal of output a bunch of data by giving my name and radius of a circle.

However, I'm not sure whether I need to pay attention of the variable locale or it is because I use the wrong way to call the function... It just didn't work.

Is there anybody would generously help me with this? Thank you very much!

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Here is Wei Wu's first in-class assignment~</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function getName(){
  var name_answer = prompt("Please enter your first and last name: ");
  return name_answer;

 }
 function getRadius(){
  var radius = Number(prompt("Please enter the radius you want: "));
  return radius;
 }

 function getCircumference() {
  var circumference_answer = 2*3.1415*radius;
  return circumference_answer;
 }

 function getAreaOfTheCircle() {
  areaOfTheCircle_answer = 3.1415*Math.pow(radius,2);
  return areaOfTheCircle_answer;
 }

 function getVolumeOfTheSphere() {
  volumeOfTheSphere_answer = (4/3)*3.1415*Math.pow(radius,3);
  return volumeOfTheSphere_answer;
 }
 function Radius(){
  this.nameOfTheUser = name_answer;
  this.radiusOfTheUser = radius;
  this.circumference = circumference_answer;
  this.areaOfTheCircle = areaOfTheCircle_answer;
  this.volumeOfTheSphere = volumeOfTheSphere_answer;
 }

 getName();
 getRadius();
 getCircumference();
 getAreaOfTheCircle();
 getVolumeOfTheSphere();
 Radius();
 document.write(Radius());
 document.write(Radius.nameOfTheUser/*['radiu']*/);
 document.write(Radius.radiusOfTheUser);
 document.write(Radius.circumference);
 document.write(Radius.areaOfTheCircle);
 document.write(Radius.volumeOfTheSphere);

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perhaps lookup, in documentation, the `new` keyword - there's also a lot more you need to learn about javascript ... calling a function that returns something, without "storing" the returned result means you discard whatever the function returns, so, it's pointless code

Comment: the variable `name_answer`, `radius` etc are local variables. You cant access it on `Radius`

Comment: Hi, could you please explain more...?

Comment: @Eddie do you think deleting all the var inside the function would work? Coz I have tried... didn't seem to work.

Comment: Removing `var` on your functions will make the variable global. You will be able to access those variable on your `Radius`

Comment: But, there are several errors also on your code. So it will not work. You have to call `Radius` as `let r = new Radius();`

Comment: And use `r` to get the values. Like `document.write(r.radiusOfTheUser);`

Comment: @Eddie first of all thank you so much for replying. I wanna know why I need to use let... I know that is a kind of block scope value...

Comment: You can use `var` actually. It really depends on how you intent to use it. I just use `let` for example purposes.

Comment: @Eddie and I don't wanna output radius onto my screen, should I use the same structure like r.blablabla? My teacher want us to use function and call it inside another function, that's basically why I used a lot of functions here...

Comment: Yes. you can to get any property of that `object` like `r.circumference`

Comment: I just chose to define them at the very top of my script... but it still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

= One issue on your code is the `name_answer`, `radius` etc are local variables. You cant access it on `Radius`. One option is, you can make it global and remove the return function. Or as what you said *"My teacher want us to use function and call it inside another function"*

You can just call `getName()` and other functions from `Radius()`

```
function Radius(){
    this.nameOfTheUser = getName();
    this.radiusOfTheUser = getRadius();
    this.circumference = getCircumference();
    this.areaOfTheCircle = getAreaOfTheCircle();
    this.volumeOfTheSphere = getVolumeOfTheSphere();
}
```

= You also have to init the Radius as `var r = new Radius();` and can access properties like `r.radiusOfTheUser`

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or
>   of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

Doc: [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

---

Here is a working code:

```
function getName(){
    name_answer = prompt("Please enter your first and last name: ");
    return name_answer;

}

function getRadius(){
    radius = Number(prompt("Please enter the radius you want: "));
    return radius;
}

function getCircumference() {
    var circumference_answer = 2*3.1415*radius;
    return circumference_answer;
}

function getAreaOfTheCircle() {
    var areaOfTheCircle_answer = 3.1415*Math.pow(radius,2);
    return areaOfTheCircle_answer;
}

function getVolumeOfTheSphere() {
    var volumeOfTheSphere_answer = (4/3)*3.1415*Math.pow(radius,3);
    return volumeOfTheSphere_answer;
}

function Radius(){
    this.nameOfTheUser = getName();
    this.radiusOfTheUser = getRadius();
    this.circumference = getCircumference();
    this.areaOfTheCircle = getAreaOfTheCircle();
    this.volumeOfTheSphere = getVolumeOfTheSphere();
}

var r = new Radius();

document.write(r.nameOfTheUser);
document.write(r.radiusOfTheUser);
document.write(r.circumference);
document.write(r.areaOfTheCircle);
document.write(r.volumeOfTheSphere);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! 
But I still can't understand why I need to define a new r to do that... and why I can't assign the variable inside other function directly to the property...

Comment: You dont need to. But you used ‘this’ on your Radius function and that is the reason why. I linked a documentation you might wanna read it

Comment: If you wont use ‘this’ and print the values directly then no need to use ‘new’

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're having a context issue.  Take, for example, your `getName` function: you declare a variable, `radius`.  `radius` is now only accessible within that functions "context".  The context of the function in this case exists from your opening curly brackets to that functions closing curly brackets.  In your next function, you attempt to pass `radius` to `Math.pow`.  This is where you're getting an error, as `radius` does not exist within this context. Here are two ways to fix this kind of error:

#### Pass a Parameter

```
function square (a) {
  return Math.pow(a, 2)  // 'a' exists in this context because 
}                        // it was passed as a parameter above

// Call it like this:
var b = square(2)  //=> 4
```

#### Set global variables

In order to make `radius` visible to all scopes, declare it in the highest one:

```
var radius = 0
var name = ''
var area = 0

// Then declare your functions
function getName () {
  // Notice that we can set name here, because it was declared in a higher scope
  name = prompt('Please enter your first and last name: ')
}

getName()
console.log(name) // again, name is accessible here
```

I'd read up here to learn more about scoping in JavaScript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, use MDN or EMCA-262. Otherwise, OK. ;-)

Comment: I intended to use the other five function inside Radius - this function, and then output the value by using document.write... but it didn't work, could you please help me do in this way? I defined them at the very top.